# using arm CMSIS on Psoc system

Tags: arm, signal-processing, core-services, cmsis, psoc

I am attempting to utilize the arm dsp cores with the Psoc5LP system from cypress. I have found examples at

http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/curset/CMSIS/Documentation/DSP/html/arm_fft_bin_example_f32_8c-example.html

Primarily the fft example is what I am interested in replicating, but I am confused slightly on how cores work. I have used the picoblaze core on Xilinx Spartan-6 before but I have never used premade cores, especially for Psoc.

I have looked at the psoc system reference guide and found information on CMSIS under startup and linking, but it does not make full sense to me. could someone please point me in the right direction to get me started? also will I have to download all the files individually that I need such as the arm_math.c for the fft example (if so I think that's the only file I need?), or will I just need to download the CMSIS version 4.3 from arms website

https://silver.arm.com/browse/CMSIS#

I'm trying to implement spectral flux analysis and autocorrelation using these cores and I think they are a good place to start.

Thanks in advance,

Scarlson

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the CMSIS package from the ARM website.
Inside of the package you will find a "CMSIS" folder which you have to copy to your project (Step #1).

Next you have to follow these steps:
http://www.cypress.com/knowledge-base-article/including-cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard-cmsis-library

Step #5 seems to be obsolete.

You now have to include the functions you want to use manually (Step #6) into the project.

For FFT this is:

- CMSIS\DSP_Lib\Source\CommonTables\arm_common_tables.c (for the
  twiddle factor table)
- CMSIS\DSP_Lib\Source\TransformFunctions\arm< type >init< format >.c
- CMSIS\DSP_Lib\Source\TransformFunctions\arm< type >init< format >.c